# How does a has_parent query work with the join datatype in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I can't make a `has_parent` query return any results when querying an index set up with the `join` datatype. I've followed the examples on [Elasticsearch's join datatype documentation page](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/parent-join.html) exactly:

Add an index containing a join between `question` (the parent) and `answer` (the child):

```
PUT my_index
{
  "settings": {
    "mapping.single_type": true
  },
  "mappings": {
    "doc": {
      "properties": {
        "my_join_field": { 
          "type": "join",
          "relations": {
            "question": "answer" 
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Add two questions:

```
PUT my_index/doc/1?refresh
{
  "text": "This is a question",
  "my_join_field": {
    "name": "question" 
  }
}

PUT my_index/doc/2?refresh
{
  "text": "This is a another question",
  "my_join_field": {
    "name": "question"
  }
}
```

Add two answers:

```
PUT my_index/doc/3?routing=1&refresh 
{
  "text": "This is an answer",
  "my_join_field": {
    "name": "answer", 
    "parent": "1" 
  }
}

PUT my_index/doc/4?routing=1&refresh
{
  "text": "This is another answer",
  "my_join_field": {
    "name": "answer",
    "parent": "1"
  }
}
```

The documentation then has no example of how to query this using a `has_parent` query. Here's my attempt, based on [the has_parent doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-has-parent-query.html), but it returns no results:

```
GET my_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "has_parent": { 
      "parent_type": "question",
      "query" : {
        "match" : { "text" : "another" }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Even though this returns one question and one answer, as expected:

```
GET my_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match" : { "text" : "another" }
  }
}
```

I'm using Elasticsearch 5.6.2.

Answer (score 0):

This is how has_parent and has_child query work with the new join datatype. For the purposes of answering your question, I used the same data for index. From your example, it appears that you would want to use has_child query instead.

```
PUT my_index
{
  "settings": {
    "mapping.single_type": true
  },
  "mappings": {
    "doc": {
      "properties": {
        "my_join_field": {
          "type": "join",
          "relations": {
            "question": "answer"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

PUT my_index/doc/1?refresh
{
  "text": "This is a question",
  "my_join_field": {
    "name": "question" 
  }
}

PUT my_index/doc/2?refresh
{
  "text": "This is a another question",
  "my_join_field": {
    "name": "question"
  }
}

PUT my_index/doc/3?routing=1&refresh 
{
  "text": "This is an answer",
  "my_join_field": {
    "name": "answer", 
    "parent": "1" 
  }
}

PUT my_index/doc/4?routing=1&refresh
{
  "text": "This is another answer",
  "my_join_field": {
    "name": "answer",
    "parent": "1"
  }
}

# has_parent query 
# added inner_hits to see what matched
GET my_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "has_parent": {
      "parent_type": "question",
      "query": {
        "match": {
          "text": "This is a question"
        }
      },
      "inner_hits": {}
    }
  }
}

# has_child query
GET my_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "has_child": {
      "type": "answer",
      "query": {
        "match": {
          "text": "another"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```